# UIActivityIndicator animations issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I have implemented `UIActivity` Indicator and added to view in `ViewDidLoad.Method` As follows:

```
 UIActivityIndicatorView *act=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    act.frame=CGRectMake(150, 240, 45, 45);
    [act startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:act];
```

But I'm not able to view the spinner rotating in the View. Can anybody tell me what's the issue?

Comment: Can you see it, but it isn't moving, or can you not see it at all? You do realise this is just a white spinner on a clear background, so if your view is white too, you won't see anything?

Comment: More info please.  Also.. with progress bars sometimes you have to do a     CFRunLoopRunInMode (CFRunLoopCopyCurrentMode(CFRunLoopGetCurrent()), 0, FALSE);
 to get it to update. What method are you doing this in?  The view controller or another one?

Answer (score 0):

Color of the spinner is white so you won't see the spinner....
just change the color before animating, you will see it.....
example:
   act.color=[UIColor redColor];